# I can't run Cisco packet tracer 7.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, cisco

I have downloaded and extracted the packet tracer file, then I used this command as root

```
chmod +x install
```

then I ran (as root)

```
./install
```

Then I used this command

```
./set_ptenv.sh
```

but whenever I run this command

```
packettracer
```

it just doesn't start

[image: This is what i get]

Comment: I think you should not run CPT as root. Try to run `packettracer` as normal user.

Comment: nah man i get an error when i try to run the application itself :  ./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5script.so.50:cant open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: just try to install missed dependency with `sudo apt-get install libqt5script5`.

Comment: still gettin that erorr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you are using CPT 7.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have found [a nice guide](https://www.tech-otaku.com/linux/getting-cisco-packet-tracer-71-to-run-on-ubuntu-1604-lts/) to run CPT.

Steps:

1. Install CPT as you have already done.
2. Download correct version of library `libicu52` (for example for amd64)

   ```
   cd /tmp
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb
   ```

3 . Launch CPT with the `packettracer`.

**Update:** this procedure works with CPT 7.1.1 too.

Comment: ok yah its working now

Comment: libicu52 or libcu55?  60?