# Troubles installing Cisco Packet Tracer 7.1 on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, libraries, cisco

During installation of Packet Tracer 7.1, I've encountered no problems. When trying to run

```
~$ packettracer
```

nothing happened, no welcome screen or anything. I then typed

```
~$ cd /opt/pt/bin
~$ ./PacketTracer7
```

which returned the following message:

```
./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To determine which libraries were missing, I issued the following command:

```
~$ ldd PacketTracer7
```

to get the list of missing libraries. The following turned out being missing:

1. `libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5`
2. `libQt5WebKit.so.5`
3. `libQt5Multimedia.so.5`
4. `libQt5PrintSupport.so.5`

My question is: how do I install those packages, because running the following command did not work:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install libQt5WebKitWidgets*
```

The error message was:

```
E: Unable to locate package libQt5WebKitWidgets*
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libQt5WebKitWidgets*'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libQt5WebKitWidgets*'
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Please read and follow [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/978167/66509) on duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks @Pero for the ldd command, I found this post first, I don't think it should be closed as duplicate. I read the other solution, it's totally different. How do I know? Because I have the same problem too and have the right solution now. Btw, have you solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libqt5webkit5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5script5 libqt5scripttools5
```

And try again.

Comment: I did exactly as you proposed, but another error message is returned: `./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5ScriptTools.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: I did manage to get it up and going using Wine.

Comment: Please see my edit above. If there are additional missing packages, I will describe how to find and install any of them.

Comment: @chili555, I followed that steps but still having the same error as @Pero Alex

`/opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5ScriptTools.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Sabrina Please see my edit above in a few moments. You will need to also install libqt5scripttools5.

Comment: After the update, I'm getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error

`user@linux:~$ /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
user@linux:~$ `

Comment: @Sabrina Please start your own new question and give us the result of: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep acket`

Comment: @chili555, just tried it on different machine, and get different error.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189983/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libqt5sql-so-5-when-installing-cisco-packe