# error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Sql.so.5 when installing Cisco Packet Tracer 7.2.2

Tags: networking, cisco

Initially, I had this problem after installing Cisco Packet Tracer 7.2.2

```
user@linux:~$ /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7
/opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
user@linux:~$
```

It turns out 5 libraries were not found.

```
user@linux:~$ ldd /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7 | grep no
    libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5 => not found
    libQt5WebKit.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Multimedia.so.5 => not found
    libQt5ScriptTools.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => not found
user@linux:~$
```

I followed suggestion from chili555 and managed to fix 4 of them
https://askubuntu.com/a/987765/769117

```
sudo apt install libqt5webkit5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5script5 libqt5scripttools5
```

Then, I launched PacketTracer7 and found another one was missed which was `libQt5Sql.so.5`.

```
user@linux:~$ /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7 
/opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Sql.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
user@linux:~$
```

Checked `ldd` again, and verified `libQt5Sql.so.5` was missing. The other 4 were fixed on previous update.

```
user@linux:~$ ldd /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7 | grep no
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => not found
user@linux:~$
```

I tried to installed it but didn't work

```
user@linux:~$ sudo apt install libQt5Sql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libQt5Sql
user@linux:~$
```

I did not see anything helpful in `syslog`

```
user@linux:~$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep acket
user@linux:~$
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Please try: `udo apt install libQt5Sql5` and try again.

Comment: Thanks @chili555 for your feedback. I'm getting this error.

`user@linux:~$ sudo apt install libQt5Sql5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libQt5Sql5
user@linux:~$ 
`

Comment: Did you start with `sudo apt update`? The package exists in all recent Ubuntu versions. Which is yours? `lsb_release -d`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. All of those libs are present in /opt/pt/bin, so if you start PacketTracer from there, it will work.

```
ana@catalyst:/opt/pt/bin$ ./PacketTracer7
```

Answer (score 1):

If after execute command "ldd yourExecutable", the end tell you "libQt5Sql.so.5 => not found", execute command:

```
apt-cache search libQt5Sql
```

to search relevant libs. The searched results:

> libqt5sql5 - Qt 5 SQL module
>
> libqt5sql5-ibase - Qt 5 Firebird database
>
> driver libqt5sql5-mysql - Qt 5 MySQL database driver
>
> libqt5sql5-odbc -Qt 5 ODBC database driver
>
> libqt5sql5-psql - Qt 5 PostgreSQL databasedriver
>
> libqt5sql5-sqlite - Qt 5 SQLite 3 database driver
>
> libqt5sql5-tds - Qt 5 FreeTDS database driver

Seeing from the results that you need "libqt5sql5". after execute command:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5sql5
```

"libQt5Sql.so.5" will be installed. if you want to know where it is installed at ,execute command

```
sudo find / -name "libQt5Sql.so.5"
```

If you need to write data into mysql, "libmysqlclient.so.21" should also be installed. execute command:

```
apt-cache search libmysqlclient
```

to search relevant libs. The searched results:

> libmysqlclient-dev - MySQL database development files
>
> libmysqlclient21 - MySQL database client library
>
> default-libmysqlclient-dev - MySQL database development files (metapackage)
>
> libcrypt-mysql-perl - Perl module to emulate the MySQL PASSWORD() function
>
> libglpk40 - linear programming kit with integer (MIP) support
>
> librust-mysqlclient-sys-dev - Auto-generated rust bindings for libmysqlclient - Rust source code

Seeing from the results that we need "libmysqlclient21", after execute command:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient21
```

"libmysqlclient.so.21" will be installed.