# Packet Tracer 7.1.1 crashes on startup, Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: xubuntu, crash, libraries, cisco

I have installed most, if not all QT libraries for packet tracer 7.1.1 to work, but now it crashes upon launching. Splash screen appears, but then the application terminates immediately.

Here's a log when launching: https://pastebin.com/iajXpJZb

Running Xubuntu 18.04.

UPDATE: The issue seems to be related to "Crypto_add_lock()" according to another error log. Not sure what this means though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have missed some dependencies, you can install them with:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5 libqt5multimedia5 \
libqt5xml5 libqt5script5 libqt5scripttools5
```

Also you can try the method from [my other answer for 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/a/978167/66509):

```
cd /tmp
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb
```

But even after these actions sometimes it really crashes with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` even if launched directly with `/opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7`.

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1039243/66509) with great idea of running it from GDB. The problem comes from some code in CPT, which is linked to LibSSL.

As it is proprietary software, you should ask Cisco for support and/or special deb-package for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: I have installed all of these dependencies, no results. I'll contact Cisco somehow to see if they can be of any help.