# PacketTracer 7 crashes on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I have updated my Ubuntu version to 18.04. Now when I try to start Packet Tracer via /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7 I get lots of those messages:

```
"Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile"
```

I also got those ones:

```
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
"INFO  - Qt Version: 5.5.1"
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
   QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled per-screen factors.
   QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen factors.
   QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
Warning: QObject::disconnect: Unexpected null parameter
Warning: QObject::disconnect: Unexpected null parameter
Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Warning: QObject::connect: No such slot CLogicalToolbar::showViewport()
Warning: QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'CBaseLogicalToolbar')
```

I also tried gitgudgithub's answer from here: [Packet Tracer 7 on Ubuntu 18.04 cannot launch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035523/packet-tracer-7-on-ubuntu-18-04-cannot-launch). Got this message as a result:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.52: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The problem is that i got libicu60 installed. I have know idea what to do. Any idea about fixing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Packet Tracer 7 on Ubuntu 18.04 cannot launch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035523/packet-tracer-7-on-ubuntu-18-04-cannot-launch) according to OP's comment on their own answer

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this! Just needed to install another version of the package. Then just execute

```
packettracer
```

And everything will work fine!

Comment: Could you please write some details in your answer? It will very useful because of the fact that many users have problem with CPT 7.1 and 7.1.1 on 18.04 LTS. They would be very happy with your method.

Comment: What I did is followed the instructions of gitgudgithub (link in the question btw). I found out that I needed to install libicui52 (this may be different for other users), so I just downloaded and installed the older version of the package. And everything went fine

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.