# Packet Tracer Segmentation Fault Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, libraries, cisco

I have installed Cisco Packet Tracer 7.1.1 on Ubuntu 18.04. Every time I launch the application it closes and give me a message `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.
Using the `gdb`, I went to the installation directory `/opt/pt/bin` and I typed the following commands:

```
$gdb Packettracer
$gdb > run
$gdb > where
```

Which reports a problem with `libpng` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0`

```
Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

Thread 1 "PacketTracer7" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff79f49a7 in CRYPTO_add_lock () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux- gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Are you using 14.04 or 18.04? Please specify correct Ubuntu version in tags and in question.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 18.04. I dont have so much point in stackexchange to use the tag for ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thank you for great debugging method, I can confirm this issue on clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. If it is possible, please report bug to Cisco. We can not change anything on Ubuntu side, I think. But they can recompile their proprietary software to support Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. We can not downgrade *libcrypto.so.1.0.0* because it is a part of `libssl1.0.0` package, which has a lot of reverse-dependencies. As alternative you may try previous version of CPT. But CPT 7.1.1 works on 16.04 LTS (see [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/978167/66509)).

Comment: What is the purpose of where command in gdb?

Comment: @Sabrina The gdb is for debugging.

Comment: @noslin005, I know that's gdb. What is the purpose of `where` command in gdb?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem in the PacketTracer implementation.

I had the same issue here, but I solved the problem using the previous version of Packet Tracer (7.0).
The Packet Tracer 7.0 is available at the [Netacad portal](https://www.netacad.com/).

Comment: @KarlRichter: it seems to be an answer...  (edited to make it clearer)

Comment: @Fabby Right. Thank you and sorry for the superficial check.

Comment: I wonder what a net academy portal has to do with packet tracer. And even more where on that page to find it without enrolling in a course.

Comment: `netacad.com` is a cisco site.

Answer (score 1):

After installing CPT:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libqt5webkit5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5xml5 libqt5script5 libqt5scripttools5
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.8_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBXTmPo8330